# matching strings with simple regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

In a Rails app I need to identify certain URLs paths that are expressed in this form:

`paths = ['/a/*/b/c', '/f/*']`

I'm in a middleware and I have access to the path, what kind of conditional should I write to check if the current URL path has a match with an entry in the provided array?

```
  path = Rack::Request.new(env).path
  included = paths.any? { |s| path.include?(s) }
```

this only checks for inclusion, but now wildcards have arrived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert paths into regular expression patterns:

```
paths = ['/a/*/b/c', '/f/*']

path = Rack::Request.new(env).path
patterns = paths.map { |path| Regexp.new path.gsub(/\*/, '[^/]+') }
    # Convert `*` to `[^/]+` to match any non-`/` characters. 
included = patterns.any? { |s| path =~ s }
```